# How do I use exec() to run external software?

Tags: rules

I am trying to use `exec()` function to run external software. This software is an .exe file.
The code that I created is given below:

```
$command = 'php sites\all\modules\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe http://testing.local:8083 sites\all\modules\nodeImage.png';
$result=exec($command);
echo $result;
```

wkhtmltoimage.exe is an program to convert webpage to an image and it needs two parameters. The first is a link to a web page, the second is the path where the created image will be saved.

This program giving an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$' in
>   C:\Users\123\Sites\drupal-7.26\sites\all\modules\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltoimage.exe
>   on line 4262

Anyone who is aware of this?

Comment: Why don't you use [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print) module. It has wkhtmltopdf support. Wouldn't it help you?

Comment: How? Cautiously. Very, very cautiously. With strict filtering and escaping all user input you pass to `exec()`ed software. Also, what line is 4262, exactly? And are you sure previous line is properly ended with `;`?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. three weeks ago I had a situation when I needed wkhtmltopdf and print module was honestly **not** an answer. Also, he needs "to image", and I don't think print module can do that.

Comment: i have used exec one time in drupal for converting videos to thumbnail.In your case exec() required mainly three things.
1.first is wkhtmltoimage.exe path that converts webpage to image.
2.web page that you want to convert(i.e. web page path).
3.output path where converted image will saved.

Comment: i need this solution for displaying nodes in mobile devices as an image. i had solved this problem a little bit. when i provide "http://testing.local:8083" it works correctly. but when i provide node path it does not works.
it goes in infinite loop..

Comment: My advice - ditch this and use phantomJS or headless chrome to snapshot a webpage to PNG or PDF.